# Displaying default UITab Bar manager from code

Tags: iphone

I have a iPhone app which uses TabBar in Navigation controller. I have a requirement like give a option to user to customize the tab order from settings panel from my app.
 Save and reloading of tabs is done perfectly.Can we invoke default tab manager from code.
Please advice on how can we use default tabs manager to display from App setting screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not possible to invoke default Tab bar edit screen. Instead we should create our own View-Controller to do the same work for us.